# OpenWRT https доступ к web интерфейсу

Tags: http, ssl, https, openwrt

Почему-то на веб интерфейс роутера заходит только через http.
Установил пакет luci-ssl (также присутствуют libcyassl libopenssl).
Роутер tp-link tl-wr1043nd v1.

OpenWrt | OpenWrt Backfire 10.03.1 | Загрузка: 0.06 0.04 0.04

При вводе https://192.168.1.1:

> Попытка соединения не удалась

Пробовал другой браузер - всё также.

---

просто reboot надо было сделать после установки luci-ssl...
но всё равно приходится ручками https вводить
пробовал

```
uci set uhttpd.main.listen_http=192.168.1.1:80
uci set uhttpd.main.listen_https='192.168.1.1:443'
uci set uhttpd.main.redirect_https='1'
uci commit
/etc/init.d/uhttpd restart
```

не перенаправляет(даже ребут делал, всё равно)

в итоге сделал так

```
uci delete uhttpd.main.listen_http ; uci commit
```

теперь http доступ просто не работает, но https всё равно вводить приходится

Comment: да кстати, было предупреждение про сертификат добавил в исключение, а где его взять?

Comment: нашел строчку на вики, не до конца разобрался                           While luci-ssl automatically installs px5g that can be utilized, you can also use openssl to generate your own certificate authority and certs, then use that certificate authority to sign the certificate you use for uhttpd. Certificates can also be named or placed in whatever directory you wish by editing /etc/config/uhttpd

Comment: тогда возникает вопрос как с помощью openssl его создать

Comment: есть какой-то пакет px5g написано можно его использовать px5g [rsakey|selfsigned]
что такое rsakey|selfsigned?

Comment: нашёл решение px5g cert надо заменить на openssl cert пока что не сделал
https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=61506